# "Assertion `cr != NULL' failed" when working with Cairo.context from different objects

Tags: gtk, cairo, vala

My program consists of 3 classes. Gtk and Cairo.Context are instantiated in one of them. Other two classes work with this context, passing it around and drawing stuff on it. However, when I try to launch the program, I get the error "Assertion `cr != NULL' failed" (cr is my Cairo.Context instance) or "Assertion`self != NULL' failed" for every method of the two secondary classes that uses Cairo.context, by either assigning it to an object's property or drawing something on it.
When I had all the code in one single class, I didn't have such problem. What can be the reason for it?

Answer (score 0):

Hard to help without a short example that isolates the problem.

I see the use of 'self' in that error message. In Vala you want 'this'. I'm also a newb, hth.